# Is it possible to rescue the leader of the Crimson Raiders before Bloodshot Ramparts?

Tags: borderlands-2

As one reaches their cell, loaders bust in to incarcerate them again. W4R-D3N, a constructor, captures them and lifts them away. It seems that the Vault Hunter is able to damage W4R-D3N, though it has always escaped in the games that I played in. Is it possible to destroy W4R-D3N before it departs from Bloodshot Stronghold?

Comment: Thank you for keeping this answer as spoiler-free as possible.

Comment: I think it could be better in that regard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.
The boss won't die even if dropped to 0 health, as seen in this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: The Wiki says, "W4R-D3N can be defeated during its first appearance at Bloodshot Ramparts". I'm asking if W4R-D3N can be defeated **BEFORE** Bloodshot Ramparts.

Comment: Found another answer, fixing this.

Comment: Its actually (at least) 1 hp: Sometimes, you can see a small bit of the healthbar, when these "immortals" are at their minimum of health.
(Easier to see on weaker enemies, which only have a few hundreds of hp in general)